# extracting optional fields in a table

Tags: database-design, relational-database

As far as I know, you should only use null on fields that you don't the value **YET**. So I come across a table that has for example this structure

```
TABLE_1
-------
ID NOT NULL,
FIELD_1 NOT NULL,
FIELD_2
```

I know for certain that FIELD_2 is not going to be updated once it is created, and it allows NULL values.

Is this a bad design of the table?

Do I have to extract FIELD_2 into another table like this?:

```
TABLE_1                  TABLE_2
-------                  -------
ID NOT NULL              TABLE_1_ID NOT NULL
FIELD_1 NOT NULL         FIELD_2 NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my oppinion, that dependens on the context of the data you are handling. I would say that state using this design is wrong, it is wrong. However, in general it is not something that should be used as it involve the use of join statements and a decrease in performance.

Unless in this desing:

```
TABLE_1                  TABLE_2
-------                  -------
ID NOT NULL              TABLE_1_ID NOT NULL
FIELD_1 NOT NULL         FIELD_2 NOT NULL
```

`TABLE_2` has a meaning (a model or another meaning by itself) you should not split your model just because `FIELD_2` could be a value that could never be assingned. In memory, a NULL field it is not expensive. So...

> Is this a bad design of the table?

No, it isnt.

> Do I have to extract FIELD_2 into another table?

No, you dont need to...